# javascript to change the color of text based on a condition

Tags: javascript, html, css

Looking for a simple java script, and the html that will change the color of the font if the values are:0-30 = green 30-60 = yellow 60-100 = red.

Excuse the poorly written psudo-ish code here...

```
    <script>
    var low=green;
    var medium=yellow;
    var error=red;

    function changeColor{

    if  var low then display green;
    if var medium then display yellow;
    if var error then display red

    }

    </script>


    <body>
    <p><font color=(changeColor)>30</font></p>
    </body>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're not "Looking for", you are "asking for us to look for you". Did you try anything?

Comment: I did, I'm sorry if my coding is that bad that it sounds like I didn't try. Forming this psuedocode was my attempt at trying to get close to an answer. The research I did just confused me more. But it looks like there are some helpful suggestions below.

Answer (score 3):

Many different ways to do this. First off don't use a `font` tag [they are deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)

### Markup

```
<p>
<span>30</span>
</p>
```

### JS

```
var colorThreshold = 10,
    spanText = document.querySelector('span');

function changeColor(val) {
    var color = "green";

    if (val > 30 && val < 60) {
        color = "yellow";
    } else if (val >= 60) {
        color = "red";
    }

    spanText.style.color = color;
}

changeColor(colorThreshold);
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/mgdUE/)**

Answer (score -2):

Better use CSS classes for such things. It's good practice if your code don't modify style directly. Learn how to use tools like JQuery (writing pure javascript takes a lot of time)
http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

HTML:

`<body><p class="change-me">30</p></body>`

Sample CSS:

```
.color1 {
    color:red;
}
.color2 {
    color:blue;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.change-me').each(function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).html()) < 30) {
        $(this).addClass('color1');
    }

    ...
});
```